# Theano GPU use: Trying to understand how to avoid transfers

Tags: python, performance, gpu, theano

I'm trying to understand how to use theano with a GPU effectively and have been looking at some simple examples related to an actual problem I am trying to solve.

First, I have the following function:

```
x = ( TFlatTimes - phase + TRP/2) % (TRP ) - TRP/2
MakeXVec = theano.function([phase], x)
```

here TFlatTimes in a float32 shared vector of ~100,000 times.  TRP is a float32 shared number and phase is a free parameter.  Essentially, given a phase, this should return a vector of times that are wrapped between -TRP/2 and +TRP/2.

If i evaluate this function 20000 times on the CPU with the following flags:

```
setenv THEANO_FLAGS 'mode=FAST_RUN,device=cpu,floatX=float32'
```

it completes in 20 seconds.

If i simply change these flags to:

```
setenv THEANO_FLAGS 'mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32'
```

it runs in 15 seconds, and if i change the function to:

```
x = ( TFlatTimes - phase + TRP/2) % (TRP ) - TRP/2
MakeXVec = theano.function([phase], sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.gpu_from_host(x))
```

it runs in 8 seconds.

This all makes sense.  Simply putting the function on a GPU speeds it up a bit, however if i specify not to transfer the x vector back it speeds up by quite a bit more.

I then tried to make the example slightly more complex:

```
x = ( TFlatTimes - phase + TRP/2) % (TRP ) - TRP/2
y = tt.exp(-0.5*(x)**2/Tg1width**2)

MakeXVec = theano.function([phase], x)
MakeYVec = theano.function([x], y)
```

and similarily:

```
x = ( TFlatTimes - phase + TRP/2) % (TRP ) - TRP/2
y = tt.exp(-0.5*(x)**2/Tg1width**2)

MakeXVec = theano.function([phase], sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.gpu_from_host(x))
MakeYVec = theano.function([x], sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.gpu_from_host(y))
```

and then compare evaluating  MakeXVec followed by MakeYVec 20,000 times either with or without the data transfer, they are both 20 seconds!

I find this very confusing.  Even if MakeYVec doesn't gain at all from not transferring the data, the version using gpu_from_host should still be faster.

I thought that this must mean that somehow there is still some data transfer going on, so i tried using the profile.  However, i don't understand the output at all:

```
Function profiling
==================
  Message: gpu.py:396
  Time in 20000 calls to Function.__call__: 4.140420e+00s
  Time in Function.fn.__call__: 3.110955e+00s (75.136%)
  Time in thunks: 2.404417e+00s (58.072%)
  Total compile time: 3.778410e-01s
    Number of Apply nodes: 6
    Theano Optimizer time: 2.160940e-01s
       Theano validate time: 4.644394e-04s
    Theano Linker time (includes C, CUDA code generation/compiling): 1.131201e-02s
       Import time 3.909349e-03s

Time in all call to theano.grad() 0.000000e+00s
Time since theano import 46.509s
Class
---
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <type> <#call> <#apply> <Class name>
  65.6%    65.6%       1.578s       3.94e-05s     C    40000       2   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuElemwise
  32.8%    98.4%       0.789s       1.97e-05s     C    40000       2   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuFromHost
   1.6%   100.0%       0.038s       9.44e-07s     C    40000       2   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuDimShuffle
   ... (remaining 0 Classes account for   0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Ops
---
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <type> <#call> <#apply> <Op name>
  42.5%    42.5%       1.022s       5.11e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{((((i0 - i1) + i2) % i3) - i2)},no_inplace}
  32.8%    75.3%       0.789s       1.97e-05s     C     40000        2   GpuFromHost
  23.1%    98.4%       0.556s       2.78e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{mul,no_inplace}
   1.6%   100.0%       0.038s       9.44e-07s     C     40000        2   GpuDimShuffle{x}
   ... (remaining 0 Ops account for   0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Apply
------
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <#call> <id> <Apply name>
  42.5%    42.5%       1.022s       5.11e-05s   20000     5   GpuElemwise{Composite{((((i0 - i1) + i2) % i3) - i2)},no_inplace}(<CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector)>, GpuDimShuffle{x}.0, GpuElemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0, GpuDimShuffle{x}.0)
  23.1%    65.6%       0.556s       2.78e-05s   20000     4   GpuElemwise{mul,no_inplace}(CudaNdarrayConstant{[ 0.5]}, GpuDimShuffle{x}.0)
  20.3%    85.9%       0.487s       2.44e-05s   20000     1   GpuFromHost(phase)
  12.6%    98.4%       0.302s       1.51e-05s   20000     0   GpuFromHost(<TensorType(float32, scalar)>)
   1.0%    99.4%       0.024s       1.19e-06s   20000     3   GpuDimShuffle{x}(GpuFromHost.0)
   0.6%   100.0%       0.014s       6.96e-07s   20000     2   GpuDimShuffle{x}(GpuFromHost.0)
   ... (remaining 0 Apply instances account for 0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Here are tips to potentially make your code run faster
                 (if you think of new ones, suggest them on the mailing list).
                 Test them first, as they are not guaranteed to always provide a speedup.
  Sorry, no tip for today.
Function profiling
==================
  Message: gpu.py:397
  Time in 20000 calls to Function.__call__: 1.929911e+01s
  Time in Function.fn.__call__: 6.424892e+00s (33.291%)
  Time in thunks: 6.052589e+00s (31.362%)
  Total compile time: 2.222779e-01s
    Number of Apply nodes: 5
    Theano Optimizer time: 6.165099e-02s
       Theano validate time: 1.147032e-03s
    Theano Linker time (includes C, CUDA code generation/compiling): 1.032209e-02s
       Import time 3.772259e-03s

Time in all call to theano.grad() 0.000000e+00s
Time since theano import 46.511s
Class
---
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <type> <#call> <#apply> <Class name>
  84.1%    84.1%       5.088s       1.27e-04s     C    40000       2   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuFromHost
  15.6%    99.7%       0.943s       2.36e-05s     C    40000       2   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuElemwise
   0.3%   100.0%       0.021s       1.05e-06s     C    20000       1   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuDimShuffle
   ... (remaining 0 Classes account for   0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Ops
---
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <type> <#call> <#apply> <Op name>
  84.1%    84.1%       5.088s       1.27e-04s     C     40000        2   GpuFromHost
   9.3%    93.3%       0.560s       2.80e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{exp(((i0 * sqr(i1)) / i2))}}[(0, 1)]
   6.3%    99.7%       0.383s       1.92e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Sqr}[(0, 0)]
   0.3%   100.0%       0.021s       1.05e-06s     C     20000        1   GpuDimShuffle{x}
   ... (remaining 0 Ops account for   0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Apply
------
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <#call> <id> <Apply name>
  68.5%    68.5%       4.145s       2.07e-04s   20000     1   GpuFromHost(<TensorType(float32, vector)>)
  15.6%    84.1%       0.944s       4.72e-05s   20000     0   GpuFromHost(<TensorType(float32, scalar)>)
   9.3%    93.3%       0.560s       2.80e-05s   20000     4   GpuElemwise{Composite{exp(((i0 * sqr(i1)) / i2))}}[(0, 1)](CudaNdarrayConstant{[-0.5]}, GpuFromHost.0, GpuElemwise{Sqr}[(0, 0)].0)
   6.3%    99.7%       0.383s       1.92e-05s   20000     3   GpuElemwise{Sqr}[(0, 0)](GpuDimShuffle{x}.0)
   0.3%   100.0%       0.021s       1.05e-06s   20000     2   GpuDimShuffle{x}(GpuFromHost.0)
   ... (remaining 0 Apply instances account for 0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Here are tips to potentially make your code run faster
                 (if you think of new ones, suggest them on the mailing list).
                 Test them first, as they are not guaranteed to always provide a speedup.
  Sorry, no tip for today.
Function profiling
==================
  Message: gpu.py:403
  Time in 20000 calls to Function.__call__: 5.344449e+00s
  Time in Function.fn.__call__: 5.037848e+00s (94.263%)
  Time in thunks: 3.975644e+00s (74.388%)
  Total compile time: 2.805271e-01s
    Number of Apply nodes: 11
    Theano Optimizer time: 1.057930e-01s
       Theano validate time: 2.398491e-03s
    Theano Linker time (includes C, CUDA code generation/compiling): 2.601004e-02s
       Import time 1.127982e-02s

Time in all call to theano.grad() 0.000000e+00s
Time since theano import 46.512s
Class
---
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <type> <#call> <#apply> <Class name>
  43.9%    43.9%       1.747s       2.18e-05s     C    80000       4   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuElemwise
  27.1%    71.0%       1.077s       5.38e-05s     C    20000       1   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuJoin
  16.5%    87.6%       0.657s       3.29e-05s     C    20000       1   theano.sandbox.rng_mrg.GPU_mrg_uniform
   8.9%    96.5%       0.353s       1.76e-05s     C    20000       1   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.HostFromGpu
   2.7%    99.1%       0.107s       1.78e-06s     C    60000       3   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuSubtensor
   0.9%   100.0%       0.034s       1.71e-06s     C    20000       1   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuReshape
   ... (remaining 0 Classes account for   0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Ops
---
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <type> <#call> <#apply> <Op name>
  27.1%    27.1%       1.077s       5.38e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuJoin
  16.5%    43.6%       0.657s       3.29e-05s     C     20000        1   GPU_mrg_uniform{CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector),inplace}
  13.9%    57.5%       0.551s       2.75e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * cos(i1))},no_inplace}
  13.8%    71.3%       0.549s       2.75e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{sqrt((i0 * log(i1)))},no_inplace}
   8.9%    80.2%       0.353s       1.76e-05s     C     20000        1   HostFromGpu
   8.2%    88.4%       0.327s       1.64e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * sin(i1))}}[(0, 0)]
   8.0%    96.5%       0.320s       1.60e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Mul}[(0, 1)]
   1.9%    98.4%       0.076s       1.89e-06s     C     40000        2   GpuSubtensor{:int64:}
   0.9%    99.2%       0.034s       1.71e-06s     C     20000        1   GpuReshape{1}
   0.8%   100.0%       0.031s       1.56e-06s     C     20000        1   GpuSubtensor{int64::}
   ... (remaining 0 Ops account for   0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Apply
------
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <#call> <id> <Apply name>
  27.1%    27.1%       1.077s       5.38e-05s   20000     7   GpuJoin(TensorConstant{0}, GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * cos(i1))},no_inplace}.0, GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * sin(i1))}}[(0, 0)].0)
  16.5%    43.6%       0.657s       3.29e-05s   20000     0   GPU_mrg_uniform{CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector),inplace}(<CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector)>, TensorConstant{(1,) of 2})
  13.9%    57.5%       0.551s       2.75e-05s   20000     5   GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * cos(i1))},no_inplace}(GpuElemwise{Composite{sqrt((i0 * log(i1)))},no_inplace}.0, GpuElemwise{Mul}[(0, 1)].0)
  13.8%    71.3%       0.549s       2.75e-05s   20000     3   GpuElemwise{Composite{sqrt((i0 * log(i1)))},no_inplace}(CudaNdarrayConstant{[-2.]}, GpuSubtensor{:int64:}.0)
   8.9%    80.2%       0.353s       1.76e-05s   20000    10   HostFromGpu(GpuReshape{1}.0)
   8.2%    88.4%       0.327s       1.64e-05s   20000     6   GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * sin(i1))}}[(0, 0)](GpuElemwise{Composite{sqrt((i0 * log(i1)))},no_inplace}.0, GpuElemwise{Mul}[(0, 1)].0)
   8.0%    96.5%       0.320s       1.60e-05s   20000     4   GpuElemwise{Mul}[(0, 1)](CudaNdarrayConstant{[ 6.28318548]}, GpuSubtensor{int64::}.0)
   1.0%    97.4%       0.039s       1.97e-06s   20000     2   GpuSubtensor{:int64:}(GPU_mrg_uniform{CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector),inplace}.1, Constant{1})
   0.9%    98.4%       0.036s       1.81e-06s   20000     8   GpuSubtensor{:int64:}(GpuJoin.0, Constant{-1})
   0.9%    99.2%       0.034s       1.71e-06s   20000     9   GpuReshape{1}(GpuSubtensor{:int64:}.0, TensorConstant{(1,) of 1})
   0.8%   100.0%       0.031s       1.56e-06s   20000     1   GpuSubtensor{int64::}(GPU_mrg_uniform{CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector),inplace}.1, Constant{1})
   ... (remaining 0 Apply instances account for 0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Here are tips to potentially make your code run faster
                 (if you think of new ones, suggest them on the mailing list).
                 Test them first, as they are not guaranteed to always provide a speedup.
  Sorry, no tip for today.
Function profiling
==================
  Message: Sum of all(3) printed profiles at exit excluding Scan op profile.
  Time in 60000 calls to Function.__call__: 2.878398e+01s
  Time in Function.fn.__call__: 1.457369e+01s (50.631%)
  Time in thunks: 1.243265e+01s (43.193%)
  Total compile time: 8.806460e-01s
    Number of Apply nodes: 6
    Theano Optimizer time: 3.835380e-01s
       Theano validate time: 4.009962e-03s
    Theano Linker time (includes C, CUDA code generation/compiling): 4.764414e-02s
       Import time 1.896143e-02s

Time in all call to theano.grad() 0.000000e+00s
Time since theano import 46.516s
Class
---
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <type> <#call> <#apply> <Class name>
  47.3%    47.3%       5.877s       7.35e-05s     C    80000       4   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuFromHost
  34.3%    81.6%       4.268s       2.67e-05s     C   160000       8   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuElemwise
   8.7%    90.3%       1.077s       5.38e-05s     C    20000       1   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuJoin
   5.3%    95.6%       0.657s       3.29e-05s     C    20000       1   theano.sandbox.rng_mrg.GPU_mrg_uniform
   2.8%    98.4%       0.353s       1.76e-05s     C    20000       1   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.HostFromGpu
   0.9%    99.3%       0.107s       1.78e-06s     C    60000       3   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuSubtensor
   0.5%    99.7%       0.059s       9.78e-07s     C    60000       3   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuDimShuffle
   0.3%   100.0%       0.034s       1.71e-06s     C    20000       1   theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.GpuReshape
   ... (remaining 0 Classes account for   0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Ops
---
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <type> <#call> <#apply> <Op name>
  47.3%    47.3%       5.877s       7.35e-05s     C     80000        4   GpuFromHost
   8.7%    55.9%       1.077s       5.38e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuJoin
   8.2%    64.2%       1.022s       5.11e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{((((i0 - i1) + i2) % i3) - i2)},no_inplace}
   5.3%    69.4%       0.657s       3.29e-05s     C     20000        1   GPU_mrg_uniform{CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector),inplace}
   4.5%    74.0%       0.560s       2.80e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{exp(((i0 * sqr(i1)) / i2))}}[(0, 1)]
   4.5%    78.4%       0.556s       2.78e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{mul,no_inplace}
   4.4%    82.8%       0.551s       2.75e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * cos(i1))},no_inplace}
   4.4%    87.3%       0.549s       2.75e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{sqrt((i0 * log(i1)))},no_inplace}
   3.1%    90.3%       0.383s       1.92e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Sqr}[(0, 0)]
   2.8%    93.2%       0.353s       1.76e-05s     C     20000        1   HostFromGpu
   2.6%    95.8%       0.327s       1.64e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * sin(i1))}}[(0, 0)]
   2.6%    98.4%       0.320s       1.60e-05s     C     20000        1   GpuElemwise{Mul}[(0, 1)]
   0.6%    99.0%       0.076s       1.89e-06s     C     40000        2   GpuSubtensor{:int64:}
   0.5%    99.5%       0.059s       9.78e-07s     C     60000        3   GpuDimShuffle{x}
   0.3%    99.7%       0.034s       1.71e-06s     C     20000        1   GpuReshape{1}
   0.3%   100.0%       0.031s       1.56e-06s     C     20000        1   GpuSubtensor{int64::}
   ... (remaining 0 Ops account for   0.00%(0.00s) of the runtime)

Apply
------
<% time> <sum %> <apply time> <time per call> <#call> <id> <Apply name>
  33.3%    33.3%       4.145s       2.07e-04s   20000     1   GpuFromHost(<TensorType(float32, vector)>)
   8.7%    42.0%       1.077s       5.38e-05s   20000     7   GpuJoin(TensorConstant{0}, GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * cos(i1))},no_inplace}.0, GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * sin(i1))}}[(0, 0)].0)
   8.2%    50.2%       1.022s       5.11e-05s   20000     5   GpuElemwise{Composite{((((i0 - i1) + i2) % i3) - i2)},no_inplace}(<CudaNdarrayType(float32,


'''
 vector)>, GpuDimShuffle{x}.0, GpuElemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0, GpuDimShuffle{x}.0)
   7.6%    57.8%       0.944s       4.72e-05s   20000     0   GpuFromHost(<TensorType(float32, scalar)>)
   5.3%    63.1%       0.657s       3.29e-05s   20000     0   GPU_mrg_uniform{CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector),inplace}(<CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector)>, TensorConstant{(1,) of 2})
   4.5%    67.6%       0.560s       2.80e-05s   20000     4   GpuElemwise{Composite{exp(((i0 * sqr(i1)) / i2))}}[(0, 1)](CudaNdarrayConstant{[-0.5]}, GpuFromHost.0, GpuElemwise{Sqr}[(0, 0)].0)
   4.5%    72.1%       0.556s       2.78e-05s   20000     4   GpuElemwise{mul,no_inplace}(CudaNdarrayConstant{[ 0.5]}, GpuDimShuffle{x}.0)
   4.4%    76.5%       0.551s       2.75e-05s   20000     5   GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * cos(i1))},no_inplace}(GpuElemwise{Composite{sqrt((i0 * log(i1)))},no_inplace}.0, GpuElemwise{Mul}[(0, 1)].0)
   4.4%    80.9%       0.549s       2.75e-05s   20000     3   GpuElemwise{Composite{sqrt((i0 * log(i1)))},no_inplace}(CudaNdarrayConstant{[-2.]}, GpuSubtensor{:int64:}.0)
   3.9%    84.8%       0.487s       2.44e-05s   20000     1   GpuFromHost(phase)
   3.1%    87.9%       0.383s       1.92e-05s   20000     3   GpuElemwise{Sqr}[(0, 0)](GpuDimShuffle{x}.0)
   2.8%    90.8%       0.353s       1.76e-05s   20000    10   HostFromGpu(GpuReshape{1}.0)
   2.6%    93.4%       0.327s       1.64e-05s   20000     6   GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * sin(i1))}}[(0, 0)](GpuElemwise{Composite{sqrt((i0 * log(i1)))},no_inplace}.0, GpuElemwise{Mul}[(0, 1)].0)
   2.6%    96.0%       0.320s       1.60e-05s   20000     4   GpuElemwise{Mul}[(0, 1)](CudaNdarrayConstant{[ 6.28318548]}, GpuSubtensor{int64::}.0)
   2.4%    98.4%       0.302s       1.51e-05s   20000     0   GpuFromHost(<TensorType(float32, scalar)>)
   0.3%    98.7%       0.039s       1.97e-06s   20000     2   GpuSubtensor{:int64:}(GPU_mrg_uniform{CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector),inplace}.1, Constant{1})
   0.3%    99.0%       0.036s       1.81e-06s   20000     8   GpuSubtensor{:int64:}(GpuJoin.0, Constant{-1})
   0.3%    99.3%       0.034s       1.71e-06s   20000     9   GpuReshape{1}(GpuSubtensor{:int64:}.0, TensorConstant{(1,) of 1})
   0.3%    99.5%       0.031s       1.56e-06s   20000     1   GpuSubtensor{int64::}(GPU_mrg_uniform{CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector),inplace}.1, Constant{1})
   0.2%    99.7%       0.024s       1.19e-06s   20000     3   GpuDimShuffle{x}(GpuFromHost.0)
   ... (remaining 2 Apply instances account for 0.28%(0.03s) of the runtime)

Here are tips to potentially make your code run faster
                 (if you think of new ones, suggest them on the mailing list).
                 Test them first, as they are not guaranteed to always provide a speedup.
  Sorry, no tip for today.
```

Could someone help me make some sense of this?  Why does specifying to not transfer the result back not make any gains when evaluating the two functions together not improve things where as it does when only evaluating the one function?  Where in this massive profile output should I try and work out what is going on?

Many thanks for any help.